# I can't open Cypress

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cypress

1. I install node js and visual studio code ,  Create a folder and open cmd
2. Input npm init
3. Input npm install cypress and wait to complete
4. I open Visual studio code and run command: 
   *" ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open "*
   But nothing is happened. Cypress can't open. 
   I tried with other way as use : *npm run cypress:open* but it's not open too.

I run on Window 10, node js 8.12, visual studio code ver 1.27.2
In other PC which cypress worked normally with Windows PowerShell in terminal but in error PC it only run with cmd.

Comment: What error message did you get?

Answer (score 15):

Use `\` instead of `/` in path for Windows:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\cypress open
```

In order to run cypress by this comand `npm run cypress:open` you need to add `"cypress:open": "cypress open"` to the `scripts` field in your `package.json` file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "cypress open"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that if Cypress has been freshly installed or updated, it must be started (once) with "npx cypress open" before the npm run script can be used.

Answer (score 5):

Add below code of line in `package.json` file

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress open"
  }
}
```

and run cypress thro' editor command prompt using below command prompt

```
npm run test
```

Answer (score 2):

Cypress Open Error- Solution for first time installer in Windows 10

A restart is required if you are trying to do it for the first time.
Execute the command .\node_modules.bin\cypress open

---

PS C:\Users\Ashwini Sambandan\cypressautomation>  node_modules.bin\cypress open
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 3.8.3

√  Verified Cypress! C:\Users\Ashwini Sambandan\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\3.8.3\Cypress

Opening Cypress...

---

Answer (score 2):

I hope you must find a solution for this. But there is no accepted answer so I to add one that worked for me.

It happens when you run cypress for the very first time.

Search for `cypress.json` or `ctrl + p` then type `cypress.json`.

Paste this in it.

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "hosts": {
    "*.localhost": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Then try `npm run cypress open` or `npx cypress open`

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to your project path

> **cd /your/project/path**

2. Install Cypress using npm

> **npm install cypress --save-dev**

3. In **package.json** file add below line inside scripts

> **"scripts": {"cypress:open": "cypress open"}**

4. In terminal enter command

> **npm run cypress:open**

Then a cypress window opens with example tests.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do in step 4. Do you run the Cypress command from VS code terminal? If so, make sure you're in the correct location. Then run your Cypress start command. It should work.

If you are in the correct location and still doesn't work, you can also try:

`npx cypress open` works like a charm in my environment and requires npm@5.2.0 or greater. Let me know your progress.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Opening-Cypress

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22474166)

Comment: Thank you for review. The link provided reveals four ways of getting Cypress to open, `npx cypress open` and also which node version you must have. No other info is really needed for this answer.

Comment: Still not a valid answer. Check [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers) on the validity of link-only answers.

Comment: "make sure you're in the correct location". lol wow took me long enough to realized i wasnt running `yarn cypress run` in the correct directory. thanks!